# Using setTitle Is make my UIButtons Disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

Category1Number = 2;
Category2Number = arc4random() %3;


switch (Category1Number) {
    case 0:
        [Category1 setTitle:(@"Sports") forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        break;
    case 1:
        [Category1 setTitle:(@"Films") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 2:
        [Category1 setTitle:(@"Music") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    default:
        break;
}

switch (Category2Number) {
    case 0:
        [Category2 setTitle:(@"Games") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 1:
        [Category2 setTitle:(@"Geography") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;
    case 2:
        [Category2 setTitle:(@"History") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }




[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

I'm using Mark Healey's tutorial on making a Quiz app but I don't seem to be getting the same result as him. What's supposed to happen is that when the view loads, the button labels should change randomly according to the arc4random method. I'm almost 100% certain I have the things connected correctly in the storyboard.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: According to your code category1 will show music always.

Comment: @MidhunMP is right. And the second switch will randomly set Category2's title. As for the setTitle method it isn't going to make the buttons disappear; there must be something else going on in your code that's doing that. Also can you provide a link to the tutorial that you're following?

Comment: Oh you guys are right, I didn't catch that, thanks!

Comment: Also It seems like i had the layering wrong for my buttons as they were under my image view -.- oops

Comment: Name your var starting with a lowercase. It's just an advice, not a solution to your issue.